# Recovering data from failed disk expansion

Tags: linux, partitioning, data-recovery, ntfs, ext4

My computer lost power in the process of expanding a partition with `gparted`.  I believe the data is recoverable.

1. Started with an NTFS partition on my 2TB HDD.
2. De-fragmented and shrunk the partition to around 700GB
3. made a new ext4 partition a little (~10GB) after the NTFS partition.
4. Copied the contents of NTFS to ext4 successfully, tested the integrity.
5. Expanded the ext4 partition over top of the NTFS partition (failed due to power loss)

I assume the data was coped in a raw manner left to right in the expansion process, due to the sizes of the data, the data located at step 4 should be untouched, but not listed.

Ive tried to use `testdisk` to recover the ext4 partition, but no luck.  I cannot find a listing that is around the scale of 700GB.  I am using Arch Linux.

---

I ask, what should I do to recover this data?

Comment: This won't help now, but for future reference: it looks like in this particular case you could have avoided expanding to the left. Next time, instead of step 5, create yet another ext4 partition where NTFS used to be; copy the data to it. In case of power loss the data is still on the source ext4 partition. If everything succeeds, delete the old partition and expand the new one (and its filesystem) to the *right*. Expanding to the right doesn't involve moving data, it just updates some metadata. It's almost instantaneous; but even if interrupted, the data should be fully recoverable in place.

Comment: Having played the wise guy in the above comment, I realy hope you will get help in your *current* situation. Good luck.